# Jquery validation - allow number without the leading zero?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validation (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) like so:

```
    var $__field = $("#selector");  
    if ($__field.is(":visible")) {  
        $__field.rules('add', { required: true });
        $__field.rules('add', { number: true });
    }
```

If the user enters a number without a leading zero, eg .5 then jquery validation says "Please enter a valid number."

How can I change the validation to allow number entry without requiring the leading zero?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is with the regular expression used for numbers.  Looking at [the latest version](http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js), lines 1021-1023, we've got:

```
number: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
},
```

The problem is that this first chunk, which looks for leading negative sign and numbers, either individual or in groups of three separated by commas, is not optional:

```
(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)
```

Tacking a `?` on the end will make it optional:

```
(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?
```

With this update, you can either modify your local copy of the plugin, changing the regular expression to the modified version, or add a [replacement validation method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) to your javascript:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("number", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)?(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid number.");
```

On any page with this `addMethod` call, the `number` validation method will be overridden to do a number validation that doesn't require a leading zero.

Comment: Thanks - this one has been unanswered for months!

Comment: Not a problem.  This bit me on a system I've been building and searching for the answer found your question.  I've emailed the plugin creator for his feedback on the regex and, if there are no issues, about getting the fix into the plugin.

Comment: Very helpful answer.  One small problem I encountered in solution: jQuery.validator.addMethod("numeric"... should be jQuery.validator.addMethod("number"

Comment: My first solution was to add a brand new validation method called "numeric" to avoid conflicts with the built-in "number".  After seeing your comment, I did some testing and sure enough, local addMethod calls override the validation method in the plugin source.  I've updated the answer to reflect your suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this fix has been incorporated into v1.10.0 of the script, released on 2012-09-07.

Comment: Official issue and pull request https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

The solution included in jQuery Validation 1.14.0 takes care of the leading zero issue but leaves a leading negative sign issue.  -.124 is invalid.  -0.124 is valid.  The RegEx provided in the posting above seems to allow -.124 so I favor it over the solution in jQuery Validation 1.14.0