# jQuery validator - Decimal not validating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery validation - allow number without the leading zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129150/jquery-validation-allow-number-without-the-leading-zero)

I am using the jQuery validator script to validate a field to ensure their is a number entered.

The number should allow for a decimal point. If I put a number before the decimal point, the validator passes (ex. 2.5). If I don't put a number before the decimal point (ex. .5) the validator fails. I need the validator to pass even with a .5

Is it a problem with the regular expression?

```
    // http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/number
    number: function(value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using * (0 or more) instead of + (1 or more):

```
/^-?(?:\d*|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much. I had been trying to figure this out for a while.

Comment: Yeah, regular expressions can be a challenge :).  Glad I could help.