# Allow text box entry without leading zero

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, numeric

I have an ASP.NET web application, my view model has a double field PowerPrice, but the validation for the field goes off if the user doesn't enter a leading zero.  The validation will say "please enter a number."  How can I allow the user to enter ".11" instead of requiring "0.11"?  Here is my view and model code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PowerPrice)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PowerPrice)
</div>

public double PowerPrice
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: So I hate to answer my own question here because I really feel like MVC should have taken care of this but I found two solutions:either write a customer validation or use a string instead of a double then do a TryParse() on it on server side.  I don't really like either one of these solutions though so I'll leave this question up to see if I get a better answer.

Comment: I have the same issue. I don't understand how .25 is not a number but 0.25 is. Same issue with putting commas in an int. I resorted to making a string in that case too.

Comment: Still no simple answer for this?  .25 == 0.25?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a value that is not of the right type in this case ".11" to an object of type Double. It will always fail.

You have a couple of options that I can think of off the top of my head.

- Change the type of the Double to String and once you get it try to
  parse it to what you want. Also on the interface to reduce what
  garbagge can be entered use a regex validator or custom validator or
  use a AjaxControlToolkit MaskEditor (see
  http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)

Or,

- You could keep your code as is and then on the client via client side code like JavaScript or JQuery detect whats there, so you said you're only worried about dot some thing like ".12", then if you detect that scenario add a leading zero or number depending on what you want to it. This will ensure on it reaching the server its a decimal value and accepted without parsing or changing on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4056007/314291) pinpoints the actual culprit - `jQuery.Validation` versions prior to 1.10 have a broken validation regex. As per the later comments on the answer, simply upgrade (e.g. `nuget`) your `jQuery.Validation` to the latest version.

In my case, upgrading from `1.9.0.1` to `1.11.1` did the trick. There is no server side / Model binder / string ViewModel changes needed at all.